# Angular 6 - HTTP Response 200 is null in subscribe

Tags: angular, post, angular6, angular-httpclient

I have the following Angular `http.service.ts` which I use to call the `/login` API.

```
login(user: User) {
    console.log("logging in");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    this.http
        .post<any>(this.loginURL, user, httpOptions)
        .subscribe(
            res => console.log('response : ' + res),
            err => console.log('error : ' + err))
}
```

This is a really standard `POST` call but it always returns `null` and I can't get why.
This is the `Network` Google Chrome's tab information

[image]

The Chrome's `Console` information

[image]

I can't get why the response is `null`. Even though I have no payload, it should at least make the `headers` available no?

Comment: Open your network tab in chrome dev tool and check the response of the post url, i guess angular has nothing to do with the response but displaying it in the console. "check your backend".

Comment: actually i did not see the response in the posted photo.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the following:

```
this.http.post("url", body, {headers: headers, observe: "response"})
   .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

You can take the same http options you have but add the observe: `response`. the header is HttpHeaders from http client. ex: `headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')`,

Comment: You can take the same http options you have but add the `observe: "response"`. the header is `HttpHeaders` from http client. ex: `headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),`

Comment: It Works !!!, Although now response.headers is an empty array even though in the Network Google Chrome's tab information I see a lot of them :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
this.http.post(loginUrl,user,httpOptions).map( res =>res).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I used the following but it still does not work. My response is still `null` : `.post(this.loginURL, user, httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(res => res))
            .subscribe(
                res => console.log('response : ' + res)`

Comment: i need to show message from using 'data' how i access 'data' in my component ?